# How to kill a process that never dies?

Tags: linux, centos6, logstash

### Problem

I have java process which does not die neither with SIGTERM nor SIGKILL.

```
logstash  2591     1 99 13:22 ?        00:01:46 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1g -Xms256m -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/jni -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -classpath : -Djruby.home=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby -Djruby.lib=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main --1.9 /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb logstash/runner.rb --path.settings /etc/logstash
```

It respawns everytime signal is received.

```
Sep 15 13:22:17 test init: logstash main process (2546) killed by KILL signal
Sep 15 13:22:17 test init: logstash main process ended, respawning
```

It sounds strange but even I reboot the server, **it still does not die**.

Process was executed through init script with below command:

```
NAME=logstash
LS_USER=logstash
LS_OPTS="--path.settings=/etc/logstash"
LS_PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid
LS_STDERR="/var/log/logstash/logstash.stderr"
DAEMON="/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash"

runuser -s /bin/sh -c "exec $DAEMON ${LS_OPTS}" ${LS_USER} &>${LS_STDERR} &
```

Is there any way to force this process to kill other than reinstalling the OS?

### Environment

Process :

```
logstash 5.0.0~alpha5
```

OS :

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
```

Java version :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Server is deployed on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Renaming one of the required files for th eprocess before killing it should prevent it from successfully restarting.

Comment: You got to behead it! That process clearly is an Highlander.

Comment: @beppe9000 And while we're in that mood, we might as well execute its parents.

Comment: As soon as I saw the title, I knew this would be Logstash

Comment: Really? Glad that I am not the only one.

Comment: Shoot it with an adamantium bullet in the head.

Comment: I did with a bullet called SIGTERM. It survived.

Comment: Nuke the entire comp from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Using `kill` to end a service is never the right way. Have a look at how init systems work.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> init: logstash main process (2546) killed by KILL signal

Actually your process does stop here.

> init: logstash main process ended, respawning

A **new** logstash process is started by init to replace it.

---

That is also shows which control process is responsible for restarting logstash: **init**. (On RHEL 6 and CentOS that is Upstart) Your process most likely gets started from either`/etc/inittab` or a drop-in file in `/etc/init/logstash.conf` (or similar) and should be controlled with the apropiate tool, `initctl` and not with `kill`.

Try `initctl list` to see if logstash is there.

Then `initctl stop logstash` will stop it.

Editing or removing the conf file in /etc/init will allow you to disable it persistently.

You might even be able to control the job with the `service` and `chkconfig` commands.

Comment: +1 for using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because logstash-relay is running ...
You should try to **stop logstash-relay**

after this check if the ps is there then **initctl list | sort**

I hope this will help you! It fixed the problem for me !

Thanks

VR

Comment: The information in the question clearly indicates that it was `init` which was responsible for respawning the process.